# Keep :format in Ruby on Rails URL helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Suppose I use a custom `:format` to implement a gadget-oriented version of my site. The general idea is that I can reuse controllers with custom, gadget-oriented views.

Is there any way to make all URL helpers called from that particular format keep the same format, without hardcoding it into all helpers?

I'd like to keep controllers untouched, and `redirect_to` calls from the controllers ignore the current format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nevermind, found an elegant solution:

```
def default_url_options(options = nil)
  options ||= {}
  options[:format] = :gadget if request.format == :gadget
  options
end
```